# How to track Dynamic Content Block?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, reporting, dynamic, email-tracking

Is there a new way (or better way) to retrieve the tracking of the Dynamic Content blocks from an Email without using impression tracking?

I saw there are few posts about this topic but from many time ago. Is there any update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [Impression Regions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_impression_tracking.htm&type=5) or manual inserts/upserts via AMPscript are the only current ways to track opens. Clicks you can utilize dynamic tracking parameters on the link to figure out the originating source - likely also utilizing AMPscript.

Impression Regions are made specifically to handle this type of tracking and do so fairly effectively. I am not sure why you would not want to utilize them - if you provide more information, I will be happy to adjust my answer. There even is the option to create impression regions without utilizing AMPscript via the [Impression Regions Using Dynamic Content](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_impression_region_dynamic.htm&type=5) which will automatically build an impression region per dynamic content block you create in the Dynamic Content Block. This means there is no technical or development require to utilize these.  There are also s[pecialized reports in Analytics Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_impression_tracking_by_job_report.htm&type=5) to pull this information and these reports are able to be automated.

You can also create a 'dynamic content tracking' DE that you manually put in Inserts/Upserts via AMPscript in your code. This then pushes the data at send time into this tracking DE to allow you to gather the custom information you want stored inside the DE.  This takes a fairly significant amount of effort as you will need a developer to create the code, an architect of some sort to ensure the dynamic content is correctly structured to efficiently and effectively collect the right information to be stored and a data architect to ensure that the data is correctly passed and that any potential pitfalls have defaults to fail gracefully. And that is just off the top of my head.

Similar to the above, you can also add in custom link tracking parameters to the links to help collect click tracking based on dynamic block. This is a bit easier to implement, but still requires a fairly high lift to ensure it comes through accurately and correctly.